# How to fix display crash for the Radeon R7 260x graphics driver?

Tags: software-installation, graphics, crash, amd, graphic-card

My display turns off after 60 minutes.

My computer is an HP Pavilion h8-1234. I have a dual boot setup of windows 7 and linux mint 13.

I replaced my old graphics card with the new Radeon R7 260x graphics card. I installed the AMD graphics driver from this link: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64. I am able to run on the windows os for several hours during intense video demand. However when I run the graphics card on my linux mint os, the display crashes about 60 minutes into the desktop session. Once the display crashes I cannot access the terminal console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to perform a soft shutdown.

What do I do to fix the display crashes?

Below is the xserver log file before the crash

```
[    28.469] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    28.469] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    28.469]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.469] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    28.469]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.469] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    28.469]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.469] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    28.469]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.469] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    28.469]    Entry deleted from font path.
...
[    28.474] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    28.474] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    28.474] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    28.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    28.541] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[    28.541]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[    28.541] Loading extension GLX
[    28.541] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    28.542] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    28.990] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    28.990]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.50.2
[    28.990]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    28.997] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    28.997] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    28.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    29.022] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    29.022]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 14.50.2
[    29.022] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:14.50.2
[    29.022] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: 14.501.1003                          
[    29.022] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Nov 20 2014 21:22:54
[    29.022] (++) using VT number 7

[    29.030] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
[    29.153] (II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
[    29.175] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    29.175] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    29.175] ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
[    29.175] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    29.175] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
[    29.299] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 10
[    29.299] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    29.344] (--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x6658) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:0:0) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:0:2) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:2:0) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:5:0) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:17:0) found
[    29.355] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:18:0) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:18:2) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:19:0) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:19:2) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:20:0) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:20:2) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:20:3) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:20:4) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:20:5) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:21:0) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:21:1) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:21:2) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:21:3) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:22:0) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@0:22:2) found
[    29.356] (WW) fglrx: No matching Device section for instance (BusID PCI:0@1:0:1) found
[    29.356] (II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0x7fb3c0e1f670
...
[    29.439] (--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
[    29.439] (WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
[    29.439] (II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0xf400000000, MCFBSize = 0x80000000)
...
[    30.865] (II) fglrx(0): Enable composite support successfully
[    30.865] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "VendorName" is not used
[    30.865] (WW) fglrx(0): Option "ModelName" is not used
[    30.866] (II) fglrx(0): X context handle = 0x1
...
[    30.941] ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib64/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/X11R6/lib32/modules/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to open /usr/lib32/dri/fglrx_dri.so, error[/usr/lib32/dri/fglrx_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX error: failed to load OpenGL driver
[    30.941] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    30.941] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    30.941] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    30.941] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
[    30.941] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
[    30.941] ukiOpenDevice: open result is 14, (OK)
[    30.941] ukiGetBusid returned 'PCI:1:0:0'
[    30.941] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
[    30.941] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.941] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card2
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card3
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card4
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card5
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card6
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card7
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card8
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card9
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card10
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card11
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card12
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card13
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card14
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card15
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: open result is -1, (No such device)
[    30.942] ukiOpenDevice: Open failed
[    30.942] ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
...
[    31.502] (II) evdev: MOSART Semi. 2.4G RF Keyboard & Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    31.502] (WW) evdev: MOSART Semi. 2.4G RF Keyboard & Mouse: ignoring absolute axes.
[    31.502] (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G RF Keyboard & Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
```

Comment: "background terminal" "ctrl-f2" ? Don't you mean "[Linux console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)" and "Ctrl + **Alt** + F2"?

Comment: @peterph Yes. Thank you for the correction. I made the edit.

Comment: Check X server log (usually `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (for disppaly `:0`). As for the Linux virtual console - it may as well be, that you actually are switched to it, but the output is garbled (none in your case). If that is the case, you may try blindly restarting X - for example (if your distribution still has the startx` script, try running it, probably on another display: `startx -- :1` (assuming display `:1` is free when your "regular" X is running. Remember that you might need to log in before that.

Comment: I will check the log. I am puzzled on how to type any commands, because I cannot see anything. Am I supposed to plug the monitor into the on-board graphics card?

Comment: If the above doesn't work for you, before doing hardware reboot, try Linux Magic SysRq, that is at least Alt+SysRq+S (sync HDDs), Alt+SysRq+U (unmount file systems), Alt+SysRq+B (reboot). See e.g. http://www.howtogeek.com/119127/use-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-linux-to-fix-frozen-x-servers-cleanly-reboot-and-run-other-low-level-commands/?PageSpeed=noscript for more details.

Comment: Using the on-board graphics card *might* help. Otherwise - make sure (before the crash), you are logged in on the Linux VT, then switch there and blindly type `startx -- :1`<Enter>. It *might* help - at least so that you won't have to reboot for a while.

Comment: @peterph I posted the log file. The log file was too big to post, I cut everything that was not registered with an (EE) or (WW).

Comment: Hence no sign of a crash - you'll need to post log **after** the crash - it might be available in `/var/log/Xorg.0.old` or you'll  need to back it up manually - after reboot do not run X11 - you'll need to tell your bootloader to pass appropriate command line to the kernel (see your distribution documentation). Also kernel log (output of `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/mesages` might give some insight into the problem). As for the length, you might want to put the excrept here and a full log somewhere else (if you don't want to paste it into the question).

Comment: Should I set kernel.sysrq = 1 or leave it on kernel.sysrq = 176 ?

Comment: just set `kernel.sysrq = 255` to enable everything. You can scale it down later.

Comment: I was unable to use the following command sudo echo “255" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq . Do I have the wrong syntax?

Comment: Switch to the default drivers. AMD drivers have surpreme compatibility issues

Comment: I am unable to switch amd drivers using driver manager. Without the installed amd drivers, the default drivers did not work. I even tried sudo apt-get update and then upgrade, which did not work.